# iOS5:An example of split view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have been searching for a good example of split view controller.
I am creating an app with textfields which when a user click on them, a pickerView pops up.

I need one for iOS5. All of examples i have seen is for 4 and i felt difficulty in modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this lecture:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/271

The video is available for free on iTunes U, and includes a demo where Prof. Hegarty goes through setting things up. Everything in this course is iOS 5 exclusively, so you may enjoy the entire course.

Enjoy,

Damien