# How to Navigate from one view to UISplitViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using UISplitViewController inside my app but whole app is not using UISplitViewController only one view using it so how can i navigate from a view to UISplitViewController and is its possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467750/ios5an-example-of-split-view-controller) & a good example is [here too](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/splitview-application-in-ipad/).